# Dealing with a "long-term mutex" type of issue?

Tags: go, mutex

My web application ingests data from a third-party source and aims to display this data to web clients over a web socket in a real-time manner. The third-party clients push data into the backend over an HTTP endpoint. The data store inside the Golang backend is of temporary nature, just a global variable: a slice keeping third-party client message content.

Since the global slice can be written to (by the third-party client ingestion endpoint) and read from (by threads that send the ingested data to web-app websockets) at any point in time, the message store reads and writes are protected with a mutex. The slice could grow and get rearranged in memory at any point of time.

A "long-term mutex" lock issue arises here. There's a thread that needs to:

- read data from the memory state
- write the data to a particular web client websocket (possibly a time-lengthy operation)

Any general patters that elegantly deal with this type of problem?

Comment: what is the nature of data & query? i.e. key value, time-series, anything else.

Comment: Can use Read-Write lock `RWMutex` and multiple sharded data structures instead of single slice to reduce the contention. Also can use channel for requesting and fetching the data. Schema, query nature & response time are  deciding factor.

Comment: Nature of the data is - just json strings that will be parsed by the web app client Javascript. No binding between web client identities and data they see either.

Comment: By query pattern, I mean for every read, entire slice is read? Same with write? If not then what is the size of slice and how it is read?

Comment: Good point, a query could be either a full memory store read (if a new web app client connects), or a new data read type of thing, based off of a client's ongoing read index.

Comment: it is unclear. My thought, just use a database engine.

Comment: In my specific case a DB isn't really necessary - I want to keep it as lightweight as possible

Comment: You can use Redis. Much faster than traditional DB.